# Search for [ ] and replace everything between it

Tags: php, full-text-search, preg-replace, replace

I have a template file that uses the structure
[FIRSTNAME]
[LASTNAME]

etc etc.... and I will be doing a search and replace on it. One thing that I would like to do is that when the template get's sent back, IF I haven't stipulated, [FIRSTNAME].... it still shows in the template... I would like to make it NULL IF I haven't stipulated any data to that variable.

in my code i'm using the FILE_GET_CONTENTS

```
$q = file_get_contents($filename);
foreach ($this->dataArray as $key => $value) 
{
    $q = str_replace('['.$key.']', $value, $q);
}
return $q;
```

So once that loop is over filling in the proper data, I need to do another search and replace for any variables left using, [FIRSTNAME]

I hope this makes sense any someone can steer me in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: so if [FIRSTNAME] isn't mapped to a value, you want to delete everything including the brackets, or leave the brackets in?  Confused by your title...

Comment: Sorry, yes, I want to remove everything between and the brackets as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to add a line like:

```
$q = preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '' , $q);
```

After all your defined substitutions, to eliminate any remaining square-bracketed words.

If you want to be concise, you can replace the whole function with a variation of the "one line template engine" at http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3444822.htm, with square brackets instead of curlies.

Comment: Ahh yeah, spot-on craig... that was perfect.

Comment: @Justin, just better hope non of your templates contain square brackets that are not for one of your keywords, because anything between those will all be deleted as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually pass arrays into the str_replace function as arguments.

```
$keys = array(
    'FIRSTNAME',
    'LASTNAME'
):

$replacements = array(
    'George',
    'Smith'
);

str_replace($keys, $replacements, $input);
```

And if you want to remove first name if its blank, why don't you just add it to the key => replacement array with a value of `''`?

```
$this->dataArray['FIRSTNAME'] = '';
```

or something like

```
if (!isset($this->dataArray['FIRSTNAME'])) {
    $this->dataArray['FIRSTNAME'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Because with the amount of templates that I have, I don't always know which data will be needed specifically. So we pass what we can, and then later information will be filled out.

Comment: @Justin huh? i'm not sure I understand how that prevents you from using the code above.

Comment: @Justin how are you generating the array that you use to do the replacements anyways? Does this come from a database?