# Replace Certain Strings With PHP Variables

Tags: php, string

In my website I have certain preset variables such as the page title, year/time, and etc.

For example in my title I would use

```
<title> <?php echo $TITLE; ?> </title>
```

However, how would I make it so typing something like..

```
<title> [TITLE] </title>
```

Will produce the same result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for \[ \] and replace everything between it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473945/search-for-and-replace-everything-between-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended that you use the PHP tags for many reasons, including performance and stability. If you want to do less typing you could use the shorthand for echoing variables: `<?= $TITLE ?>`.

If you're using a PHP version prior to 5.4 you might have to enable `short_open_tags` in your configuration. [After version 5.4 these tags are always available](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

If you're dead set on using a different syntax for your HTML, you could look into a templating language like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = str_replace('[TITLE]', $title, $page);
```

Replace `$page` with your variable. Obviously then you'd have to echo out `$page` to get it to show.

Answer (score 0):

That effect can be accomplished with template tags in a template engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a PHP [templating language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) like Mustache or Smarty.

[PHP vs template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731743/php-vs-template-engine) might point you towards some other options.